# LATEST LTS EDITION IS NOT GETTING DETECTED FROM THE TERMINAL

Tags: command-line, 22.04, lts, do-release-upgrade, automatic

I am using 20.4.04 LTS version. When I am trying to use `sudo do-release-upgrade` it's not detecting the latest 22.04 LTS version.
[image: Error]

**Note*** *I can do the upgrade manually but some software can't be installed again.So it has to be automatic. And I also change the `Prompt=normal` which is only detecting 20.10.*

Please help me.

Comment: The [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS announcemts](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/04/21/ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish-released/) said "*Users of Ubuntu 21.10 will soon be offered an automatic upgrade to 22.04. Users of 20.04 LTS will be offered the automatic upgrade when 22.04.1 LTS is released, which is scheduled for the 4th of August. For further information about upgrading, see:..*" where it's not 4-August-2022 yet

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 isn't offered; it's EOL (see https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/) though that was likely a *typo* as 21.10 is an offered upgrade, and will be until [Ubuntu 21.10 reaches EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS announcemts](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/04/21/ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish-released/) said

> "*Users of Ubuntu 21.10 will soon be offered an automatic upgrade to
> 22.04. Users of 20.04 LTS will be offered the automatic upgrade when 22.04.1 LTS is released, which is scheduled for the 4th of August. For further information about upgrading, see:..*"

where it's not 4-August-2022 yet, and that date (4 August) is a Thursday which refers to the ISO release date, it's normal for the *taps* to be turned the subsequent earliest week or weeks, or when the *Ubuntu Release Team* deem the upgrade as perfect as it can be; after all LTS users usually '*prize stability*'.